# jQuery chaining if-statement

Tags: jquery, chaining

I am making a table display optimization of my website when the windows width gets below 500px, in which I want the tables to only have 2 columns; Title, Teaser.

As of now I am chaining like this:

```
var $rows = $(".zn-listviewtable tr");
if ($rows.children('td').length > 3) {
    $rows.find("td:gt(2)").remove().end().find("th:gt(2)").remove().end().find("td:lt(1)").remove().end().find("th:lt(1)").remove();
}
```

As you can see I have an if-statement checking if there's more than 3 columns (or `td`'s) and if so, then remove all that is `>` 2 and `<` 1.

The only field which is `<` 1 is a checkbox field in each row. Not all my tables has this field, so I only want to apply the `remove()` on those which does have it.

Is there a way to check of this during the chaining rather than splitting it up and then start all over in a seperate one, avoiding it ending up like this:

```
var $rows = $(".zn-listviewtable tr");
if ($rows.children('td').length > 3) {
    $rows.find("td:gt(2)").remove().end().find("th:gt(2)").remove();
}
if ($rows.children('td').find('input:checkbox').length > 0) {
    $rows.find("td:lt(1)").remove().end().find("th:lt(1)").remove();
}
```

Comment: Maybe just a personal taste thing, but I'd avoid the single-line-chaining and try and make the code simple and clear. If that involves temp vars then so be it. Adding a class name to the columns may also make the code easier to read, and avoid column indexes. E.g. `$rows.find(".col1, .col4, .col5").remove()`, where col1, col4 and col5 are sensible names for your cols (e.g. .title, .teaser).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's easier to write:

```
$rows.find("td:gt(2)").remove().end().find("th:gt(2)").remove().end().find("td:lt(1)").remove().end().find("th:lt(1)").remove();
```

as:

```
$rows.find("td:gt(2),th:gt(2),td:eq(0),th:eq(0)").remove();
```

If you want to chain everything you'll need to assign a class to `table`s that have a first column of checkboxes (or the first `td`s and `th`)

Otherwise, you can:

```
if ($rows.find('td:eq(0):has(input[type="checkbox"])').length)
    $rows.find("td:eq(0),th:eq(0)").remove();

$rows.find("td:gt(1),th:gt(1)").remove();
```

Which conditionally removes the checkbox column, and leaves 2 columns

Answer (score 2):

You’re looking for this plugin: [jQuery iff: A chainable "if" statement](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-iff-plugin/)

It allows you to rewrite this:

```
function my_test( x ) {
  return x === 'bar';
}

var elem = $('div');
elem.append( '1' );
if ( my_test( 'foo' ) ) {
  elem.append( '2' );
}
elem.append( '3' );
```

…into this:

```
function my_test( x ) {
  return x === 'bar';
}

$('div')
  .append( '1' )
  .iff( my_test, 'foo' )
    .append( '2' )
    .end()
  .append( '3' );
```

In each example, `'2'` is not appended between `'1'` and `'3'` because the `my_test` function call returns `false`.

If the argument passed to `iff` is `true`, or is a function that, when invoked, returns `true`, all selected elements are passed through. Otherwise, all elements will be removed, and an empty jQuery object will be passed through. If a function reference is passed, any following arguments will be passed to that function.

Inside the callback, `this` refers to the jQuery collection of elements. Note that `iff` is considered a ‘destructive’ traversing operation, and can be reverted with `.end()`, even if no elements were removed.

Your code could be rewritten as follows:

```
$(".zn-listviewtable tr")
  .iif(function() {
    return this.children('td').length > 3;
  })
    .find("td:gt(2), th:gt(2), td:lt(1), th:lt(1)").remove();
```